# .gitignore difference between *.class and .class

Tags: git, gitignore

What's the difference between those two lines in .gitignore file?

```
*.class
.class
```

Comment: `.class` matches files whose filename is literally `.class`. The other one matches any file whose filename ends with `.class`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.gitignore` is able to use globs, thus by inserting `*.class` you are ignoring all entries which ends with `.class` whereas in second case you are excluding only `.class` file.

More information about .gitignore entries could be found in [this document](http://schacon.github.io/git/gitignore.html#_pattern_format).